# How to limit angles realistically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

The character of my game is a cat; it can walk and jump. The problem is that the ground has slopes and holes, so the cat flips on the back sometimes, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to realistically limit rotation angles? I.e. from -45 to 45 degrees, so it is compatible with the physics engine.

I found solutions to set angles directly as `transform.rotation = desired Rotation` but it produces artifacts with physics and it doesn't look realistic when the object has begun to rotate and suddenly stopped.

**UPD:** I tried an offered solution from answers:

```
private void FixRotation()
{
    var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    Debug.Log("Limiting angles: " + minAngle + "; " + maxAngle);
    Debug.Log("Rotation Z: " + angles.z);
    angles.z = Mathf.Clamp(angles.z, minAngle, maxAngle);
    transform.eulerAngles = angles;
    Debug.Log("Fixed rotation Z: " + transform.eulerAngles.z);
}
```

It doesn't work correctly. When the cat is going to rotate more limits, it returns back as I need **BUT** the sprite begins to shake very quickly. Am I doing wrog a something?

Comment: Check out Mathf.clamp and play around with different angle ranges https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Can you look at my function, pls, I've updated my question?

Comment: When I've switched to Euler angles, it begun to limit angles but it looks crazy. The cat's sprite shakes just trying to restore the rotations to limits.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with shaking using a solution from [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/141891/view.html).

```
private float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < 90 || angle > 270)
    {   
        // if angle in the critic region...
        if (angle > 180)
        {
            angle -= 360;  // convert all angles to -180..+180
        }

        if (max > 180)
        {
            max -= 360;
        }

        if (min > 180)
        {
            min -= 360;
        }
    }

    angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);

    if (angle < 0)
    {
        angle += 360;  // if angle negative, convert to 0..360
    }

    return angle;
}

private void FixRotation()
{
    var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    angles.z = ClampAngle(angles.z, minAngle, maxAngle);
    transform.eulerAngles = angles;
}
```

The idea of solution that we need to prevent a full rotation of game object when its angles are in the critical regions (more or less 180)